# String in struct in struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

So I've to do another exercise. This time I need to define a struct and a 100-elements array, which will store information about the book (title, author, ID number, price) and a simple function which will print info about all of the books stored. I started with that code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct name_surname {string name, surname;};
    struct book {string title; name_surname author_name, author_surname; int ID; int price;};
    return 0;
}
```

And, well, what now? How can I store this in an array?

Comment: It seems like, in your `book` your `author_name` has a `name` and a `surname` and so does your `author_surname`...? Seems like a little overkill on the names?

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Clearly if you pick up a textbook and study, you will know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create an array of type book or name_surname or whatever you want.

Example:

```
book arr[100];

arr[0].title = "The last robot";
arr[0].ID = 2753;
```

Tips:

It's good programming practice if your structs/classes begin with with capital letter, so it's easier to distinguish them and so it is easier to name the variable the same name just without the capital letter. Example.

```
struct Name_surname 
{
    string name, surname;
};

Name_surname name_surname[100];
name_surname[0].name = "MyName";
```

Another tip is that I'd really suggest you learn how to research, this question has been answered millions of times and answers are all over the internet.

Comment: It's not typically a good practice to mix PascalCase and underscores, though.

Comment: Many folks don't think that naming classes with capital letters is "good programming practice".

Answer (score 0):

Here  is  my  suggestion  :

```
struct book 
{
    string title; 
    string name_surname;
    string author_name;
    string author_surname;
    int ID; 
    int price;
};


struct  Database
{
     book *array;
     void  printDatabase()
     {
         for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ;i++)
                cout<<array[i].title<<endl;
     }

    Database()
    {
        array =  new string [100];
    }


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name structure seems a little confused but creating an *array* is simply a case of declaring a variable with `[]` appended to it giving the size.

For example:

```
struct full_name
{
    std::string firstname;
    std::string surname;
};

struct book
{
    std::string title;
    full_name author;
    int ID;
    int price;
};

int main()
{
    // Declare an array using []
    book books[100]; // 100 book objects

    // access elements of the array using [n]
    // where n = 0 - 99
    books[0].ID = 1;
    books[0].title = "Learn To Program In 21 years";
    books[0].author.firstname = "Idont";
    books[0].author.surname = "Getoutalot";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about that:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct book {string title; string name; int ID; int price;} tab[100];

void input(book[]);
void print(book[]);

int main()
{
    input(tab);
    print (tab);
    return 0;
}

void input(book tab[])
{
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nBook number: "<<i+1<<endl;
        cout<<"title: ";cin>>tab[i].title;
        cout<<"name: ";cin>>tab[i].name;
        cout<<"ID: ";cin>>tab[i].ID;
        cout<<"price: ";cin>>tab[i].price;
    }
}

void print (book tab[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nBook number: "<<i+1<<endl;
        cout<<"title: "<<tab[i].title;
        cout<<"\nname: "<<tab[i].name;
        cout<<"\nID: "<<tab[i].ID;
        cout<<"\nprice: \n"<<tab[i].price;
    }
}
```

I've done this with help from some Yt video. It works, but, is there a way to do it better, or just leave it how it is? And I have a question: Why those function parameters? Can't I just say `tab[]` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Computer languages are based on general and recursive rules. Just try to experiment and extrapolate with the basic understanding to build seemingly complex stuff. Coming to what you are trying to achieve:

- We know, an array can be declared for any data-type (primitive or derived, one might call them POD and ADT).
- We know, struct can comprise of any number of elements of any data-types.
- Now, we can see that it is just as natural to say MyStruct[] as it is to int[].

It is better to prefer `std::array` if using modern compiler.